# Is it possible to choose location of firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Due to the laws personal data must be stored on the territory of Russia. Is there possibility to choose place where data will be placed?

Comment: Answer is : **NO**

Comment: @jankigadhiya It means that firebase cannot be used on territory of Russia... What's the alternative?

Comment: It means it is not possible **to choose place where data will be placed in firebase**..!! There is no alternative..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya That leads to problem with law-> It means that firebase cannot be used on territory of Russia. So sad =(